# Python: How receive values from an input function and have them working as an integer?

Tags: python, integer

I am currently writing a program that receives input from users and processes them in separate functions.
MRE:

```
def prompt_user():
    money1 = input("insert a value")
    money2 = input(" insert another value")
    return money1, money2

def add(money1, money2):
    cash = int(money1) + int(money2)
    return cash

two_values = prompt_user()
total = add(*two_values)
print("you have "+ str(total))
```

My problem with the code above is that it's really ugly. How am I able to process the data from users WITHOUT writing int() for every variable I used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `map`:

```py
def prompt_user():
    money1 = input("insert a value")
    money2 = input(" insert another value")
    return map(int, (money1, money2))
```

Or you can create a function named `input_int(text)` to avoid duplication:

```py
def input_int(text=""):
    return int(input(text))

def prompt_user():
    money1 = input_int("insert a value")
    money2 = input_int(" insert another value")
    return money1, money2
```

Here is a better version of `input_int(text)`:

```py
def input_int(text=""):
    while True:
        try:
            res = int(input(text))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("The input must be an integer")
    return res
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to cast the input to integer at a point. Better approach will be to use `int()` on `input()` and `.format()`:

```
def prompt_user():
    money1 = int(input("insert a value"))
    money2 = int(input(" insert another value"))
    return money1, money2

def add(money1, money2):
    cash = money1 + money2
    return cash

two_values = prompt_user()
total = add(*two_values)
print("you have {}".format(total))
```